# Meteor Publish fetch non empty arrays

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This issue is driving me nuts. I need a code in Meteor.publish to get non empty arrays of objects.

A sample structure is shown below (field names here are arbitrary, I am just presenting the structure) -

```
  Books:{
    _id:'xyz',
    name:'book1',
    image:[binary array],
    pages:[
       {
          id:1,
          name:'page1', 
          author:'ueye',
          picture:[binary array]
          chapters:{
              mon:[
                {
                   chapter1:'zzz',
                   chapter2:'xxx'
                }
             ],     
             tue:[
               {  
                  chapter1:'123',
                  chapter2:'yyy'
               }
             ],
            wed:[],
            thu:[],
            fri:[],
            wkd:[],
          }
         },                    
        {
         id:2,
         name:'page2',
         author:'asfnwro',
         picture:[binary array],
         chapters:{
              mon:[
                {
                  chapter1:'xyz',
                  chapter2:'uuu'
                }
             ],     
             tue:[],
             wed:[
               {
                 chapter1:'7777',
                 chapter2:'ieismxi',
               }
             ],
             thu:[],
             fri:[],
             wkd:[],
         }
       }      
    ]
}
```

In this example you see I have one 'tue' with empty array (look at the end). I want to fetch all 'chapters.tue' that are not empty.
Note that I do not want the whole document only (in this example) 'pages.id', 'pages.name','pages.picture' and all fields from 'chapters.tue' for those arrays ('chapters.tue') that are not empty.
It is guaranteed that chapters will always have array for every day of the week but these arrays themselves may or may not have elements. When these arrays are populated the structure is always the same (in the above example you will always have chapter1 and you will always have chapter2 in the array).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So far I got this -

```
db.myDoc.aggregate([
    {$match:{'_id':'xyz'}},
    {$unwind:'$pages'},
    {$match:{'pages.chapters.tue':{$not:{$size:0}}}},
    {$project:{'name':1, 'pages.chapters.tue':1}},
    {$group:{'_id': '$_id','name': {$first:'$name'},
        'chapters': { $addToSet:'$pages.chapters.tue'}}        
    }    
 ])
```

Comment: You can not use Mongo aggregation with Meteor publish, only Meteor method

Comment: Any suggestion then how can I accomplish the above with Meteor Publish?

Comment: I think you should decouple your collection, create three separate collections: `myDoc`, `pages`, `bags`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I ended up doing -
I found a package 'reactive aggregate' one can use to get reactivity from MongoDB aggregate.
However, aggregate was not suitable for me because it was getting pretty complex. Double projections and double grouping for something I thought should be simple. I did not want to break down my collection into smaller collections because this structure makes sense to me (book has pages and each page has chapters and in this case the chapters are spread across the days of the week).  To start breaking this collection into multiple collections just so that I can 'group by' brings me back to SQL server.

I ended up using 'find' on the collection with projection of the fields that I need.  Trouble is 'find' works on a document level so you still get empty arrays. I used a Meteor package called 'publish-composite' to publish this subscription into a client only collection (so that I do not end up with a union against other subscriptions that I have in my application for the same 'books' collection). I do the filtering on the client (that is, I detect on the client which arrays are empty and only present the populated arrays).

If anyone on here knows of a simple aggregate pipeline to achieve this functionality I am still more than happy to learn.